# What was the page with community FAQ and posts about different technologies?

Tags: support

I remember a few months ago I visited some page on SO about C++ and it was something like community guide with FAQ about this technology (a little bit similar to "info", but more informative and classy). I can't find it now. I already checked "SO guide page" and didn't find any mentioning about this page.

Comment: anyone of those: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B-faq%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: @rene hm, was the "c++ tag wiki" redesigned? bc i remember it was styled in a form of mini articles (copy-pasted form answers).

Comment: not recently: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4127552/revisions

Comment: @rene well, some googling led me to SO Documentation that was closed recently :( That was that community guide :) thank you for your help.

Comment: ah, yes. I've already wiped SO Documentation  from my memory for being a bad dream ...

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ I was trying to find appeared to be the closed SO Documentation project.